# VBA If 2 cells in a column are equal, number the row in column b

Tags: vba, loops, numbers, cell, offset

i'm wondering if someone could help me resolve this stuff.

i try to make something which seems to be rather easy:

i have a list of names in column A.

- name 1
- name 2
- name 3
- name 4
  etc

if such thing occurs :

- name 1
- name 1
- name 1

then it should offset in column B a number (which i will concatenate after, but that's not a problem)

it should be like this

- name 1-1
- name 1-2
- name 1-3

i've made the following macro which runs but surprisingly does'nt return error message. nevertheless, nothing happens.

```
    Sub test()

Dim ColonneA As Range
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Variant
Dim z As Integer

Set ColonneA = Range("A1:A20")
z = ColonneA.End(xlDown).Rows.Count
'HERE I DON'T KNOW HOW TO LINK z AND x
z = z - 1
y = z

i = 0

Do While x <> ""
 For Each x In ColonneA
 For Each y In ColonneA
 If x = y Then x = x.Offset(0, i)

 i = i + 1

 Next y

 Next x
Loop

End

End Sub
```

i'm mixed with variants i think.

besides, does anyone know if a kind of Codecademy for VBA exists?

thank you for reading

best regards

Comment: You should watch this series:[Excel VBA Introduction - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: You should also install [Rubberduck VBA](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiOhpLs7MfWAhXBSSYKHQRdBT4QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frubberduckvba.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNEO2k5MUF7bPQlsEKo0lWsEV5yJSw).  It has many features that will help you debug your code.  My favorite feature is code indent.  Properly indented code will help you find errors.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Worksheet Formula `COUNTIF` and a mix of relative and absolute references.

```
"=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)". 

Sub CountDuplicates()
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
            .Formula = "=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```